# Google Studio Count Distinct return with wrong value

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I am trying to `count_distinct` the invoice number from a table (using Google Sheets as data source). The invoice numbers may be numeric or alphanumeric. The problem is the `count_distinct` only counts *numeric* invoice numbers, while *alphanumeric* ones are not included in the count.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is presumably that the column in formated as numbers in Google Sheets and therefore all alphanumeric fields are transmitted as `null` to Data Studio. Changing the column to text-formation in Data Studio does not solve the issue.

The only way is to format this column in Sheets as text.